# Add "/blog/" as base for all blog post URL

Tags: permalinks, options

I want to add `/blog/` as base for all blog post URLs on my website. Only issue is, I already have a page with the permalink as `/blog/`. So now the permalink settings are not allowing me to update as `/blog/%postname%/`. How do I achieve this so that I can have a page with slug `/blog/` and also have all the blog post permalink as `/blog/my-post-name` ?

Answer (score 0):

On the page edit screen, Quick Edit the existing page and change the slug to something else temporarily. *Then* go and save your permalinks. Once that works you can go back and change the page's slug back to `blog`.